# Finding closest element value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <div><img src="1.jpg">text<span class="get">aa</span> <span class="click">Get value</span></div></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <div><img src="2.jpg">text<span class="get">bb</span> <span class="click">Get value</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div><img src="1.jpg">text<span class="get">cc</span> <span class="click">Get value</span></div></div>
        </td></tr>
</table>
```

How do i get closest value of class get when class click is clicked?

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $('#sample').text($(document).closest('div').find('.get').text());
    });
});
```

this not working, it return empty..

Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "closest"?

Comment: if you see my html codes, there are multiple instances of class "get" and "click", so whenever i press class "click", class "ge"t closest to class "get" should get displayed value.

Comment: 'closest' selects your closest matching DOM ancestor, is that what you're going for? http://api.jquery.com/closest/   Without looking too closely, I think @zerkms might be on the right track with siblings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.click').click(function() {
  $('#sample').text($(this).siblings('.get').text());
});
```

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rcXka/

Comment: Yeah you can't find siblings with closest can you?

Comment: @drachenstern: i bet - no. Anyway - it is a working sample at jsfiddle ;-)

Comment: you are too motivated, I can't be arsed to spool up jsfiddle at this time of night ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the markup you demonstrated, this should do what you want:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('#sample').text($(this).siblings('.get').text());
});
```

Note that if there are multiple siblings with the class of `get`, this may not do what you want. It'll return the first sibling with that class, rather than the "closest" in the markup -- you'll need to come up with a more strict definition of "closest" if there will be multiple siblings `.get`s.

Also,

```
$(this).each(function(){ ... });
```

Is a meaningless statement. That means "execute this function once for each element in the set of matched elements", but there's only one element in the set of matched elements, namely `$(this)`. You can replace it with just the contents of the anonymous function.

The `.closest()` function returns the first *parent* element that matches the specific selector. So it doesn't make sense to call `$(document).closet()` -- `document` has no parents.

Comment: @Dan - Not sure where you got that idea -- zerkms posted that while I was typing this, about 2 minutes before me. Thanks for the downvote, though.

Comment: It said "answered 2 hours ago" on his and "answered 1 hour ago" on yours

Comment: @Dan - Looks like you viewed it in the 2 minute window where the integral hours is different. It's a reasonable downvote either way, since our two answers are identical and all.